# google smtp is not working on deployment but it works on local server

Tags: smtp, gmail, laravel-5.8

google smtp works fine on local server but after deployment it gives me that error

> **exception: "Swift_TransportException" file:
>   "/home/sellective/public_html/sellective/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php"
>   line: 269 message: "Connection could not be established with host
>   smtp.googlemail.com"**

my credentials are right .
I've tried another account , another port and another encryption method also not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stacked with similar problem few days ago. But I used PHPMailer to get gmail SMTP server connection. Maybe, your server belongs to goDaddy domains. PHPMailer wiki say this:

> Popular US hosting provider GoDaddy imposes very strict (to the point
>   of becoming almost useless) constraints on sending an email. They
>   block outbound SMTP to ports 25, 465 and 587 to all servers **except
>   their own.**

So, probably, you can't use google SMTP from your present server.

Use WhoIs services to check who is Registrar of your hosting.

Comment: yes my server belongs to goDaddy domains .
so what should I do to be able to send smtp emails with this server?

Answer (score 0):

goDaddy prevent smtp service from other hosts. only its own service works so I used 
"relay-hosting.secureserver.com" as mail host and  mail port "25" with no encryption . goDaddy encrypt it for you .